# Scala, importing class

Tags: scala, import

I have two files:

logic.scala and main.scala

logic.scala contains one class and main.scala have one class with method main (to run it). And I want to import a class from logic.scala and use this class to create object(s) and work with them.
How to import and compile it in proper way?

Comment: As far as Scala packages and imports are concerned, have a look here: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/119
and for compilation and execution of Scala code look here: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/166

If you edit your question and add some example code to illustrate your problem I'm sure you will get more specific help.

Comment: Without making any recommendation on how you organize your code, you should be aware that the Java requirement of public classes being one-to-one with source files *does not exist* in Scala. You have the option of sorting classes into files in pretty much any way you find appropriate. The only exception are the `sealed` concept and the *companion* `class` + `object` concept.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

- `logic.scala` code

> ```
> package logic
>
> class Logic{
>
>   def hello = "hello"
>
> }
> ```

- `main.scala` code

> ```
> package runtime
>
> import logic.Logic  // import
>
> object Main extends Application{
>
>   println(new Logic hello) // instantiation and invocation
>
> }
> ```

- compile the files with `scalac`

> ```
> scalac *.scala
> ```

- run your application with `scala`

> ```
> scala -cp . runtime.Main
> ```

Comment: The **Application** trait is deprecated, so it is recommended to use the **App** trait instead.

Comment: This code gives me this error: 
src/main/scala/main.scala:3: error: not found: object logic
import logic.Logic  // import
       ^
src/main/scala/main.scala:7: error: not found: type Logic
  println(new Logic hello) // instantiation and invocation
              ^