# how to import a class in scala

Tags: scala, import, package

I am learning `scala` recently, the package in `scala` confused me.

I have a file named `StockPriceFinder.scala`:

```
// StockPriceFinder.scala
object StockPriceFinder {
    def getTickersAndUnits() = {
        val stockAndUnitsXML = scala.xml.XML.load("stocks.xml")

        (Map[String, Int]() /: (stocksAndUnitsXML \ "symbol")) {
            (map, symbolNode) => 
                val ticker = (symbolNode \ "@ticker").toString
                val units = (symbolNode \ "units").text.toInt
                map ++ Map(ticker -> units)
        }
    }
}
```

then I want to use `StockPriceFinder` in `test.scala` which is in the same folder:

```
val symbolAndUnits = StockPriceFinder.getTickersAndUnits
```

but when I run it with `scala test.scala`, I got error:`error: not found: value StockPriceFinder`. In Java, if this two source files are in the same folder, I do not need to import and I can use it directly, so how can I import `StockPriceFinder` correctly in scala?

I have tried to use `import StockPriceFinder` in `test.scala`, but it still does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala, importing class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075951/scala-importing-class)

Comment: @LionelPort I have tried to use `import StockPriceFinder` in `test.scala`, but it still does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to `import StockPriceFinder` if the files are in the same *package* (not folder).

But you do need to compile `StockPriceFinder.scala` first and pass the correct classpath to `scala`.

```
scalac StockPriceFinder.scala
scala -cp . test.scala
```

should work (might be a bit off). However, you shouldn't do it manually, since it becomes unmanageable very quickly; use [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/) or other build tools (Maven, Gradle).

Comment: if I do not need `StockPriceFinder`, I just use `scala test.scala` it will run normally without compiling. So if I need to compile the file if I refer this file in some other place?

Comment: It doesn't "run without compiling", `scala` just takes care of compiling it for you. But it doesn't know where it should get `StockPriceFinder` from.