# Importing object without class

Tags: scala

I'm trying to import an object from another .scala file that doesn't exist inside a class. I've found you can import a class like in here [Scala, importing class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075951/scala-importing-class). Is there a way to import an object without having a class around it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing a class and importing an object work the same in scala.

If you have a class

```
package com.package1

class MyClass{}
```

and an object

```
package com.package2

object MyObject{}
```

You import both the exact same way

```
package com.package3

import com.package1.MyClass
import com.package2.MyObject
```

import syntax is the same no matter what you are importing,  whether it's an object, a class, a trait, a method, or a  field

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Scala can do exactly what you ask, and this is used frequently. Here is an example:

```
object Blah {
  val x = 1
  val y = "hello"
}

object Main extends App {
  import Blah._
  println(s"x=$x; y=$y")
}
```

Output is:

```
x=1; y=hello
```

You can also import members of a class instance, which blew my mind the first time I saw it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about companion objects, they are not defined inside a class, but after the class definition:

```
class AClass {
def sayHello() = {
    println(AClass.Hello)
   }
}

object AClass {
   private val Hello = "hello"
}
```

You should have no problem importing it.